# Native (iOS or Android) Facebook login using popup dialog only?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, authentication, single-sign-on

I have iOS and Android apps built and working with the FB SDK, but I've only ever seen two Login Dialog styles:
* Switch to the installed Facebook App for auth, and
* Embedded WebView/Safari online auth.

Lots of other apps seem to achieve this using a simple, native popup dialog, and Facebook seem to indicate that this is still possible, as in the following image from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0

Anyone know how to force or indicate a preference for the popup? A 48 hour search of the Net has no turned anything up that seems even vaguely current.

Thanks in advance.

Image at: https://scontent-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/l/t39.2178-6/851582_133467196842050_800025839_n.png (not enough rep points to post inline!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal native popup dialogs are not supported in Login V2, which launched yesterday at f8 (there are a few exceptions). The SDKs will try to use the most optimal method of displaying the dialog, preferring to fast app switch to the Facebook app.

Comment: Thanks Sean - yeah, that looked to be the case. Do you know what the lifetime of the v1.0 support is? FYI, we're having problems with the fast-app-switch (calling something "fast" doesn't make it fast!), in that our app needs a lot of work to retain state to make it recover from being switched out by iOS.

Answer (score 0):

For IOS If you download the FB-IOS SDK the sample app "HelloFacebookSample.xcodeproj uses the FBLoginViewclass which you can configure to what you want. Similar facilities should be available for Android.

Comment: Thanks Paolo. Can I ask what version of the SDK you're using? As Sean says above, it looks to have disappeared from the lastest SDK (3.14).

Comment: Hi Mat, I may have misunderstood your question, I believe was using 3.09 or 3.10  the sample code I was referring however is in the current SDK. It does not do a popup although you can change the code to invoke login from a pop up or as specified in the FB documentation you mentioned. FB has an OAUTH web services endpoint that you can use to program the login. If you wish something pre-built I suggest you check IOS7 social framework, it has limited capabilities compared to using the SDK but is able to do simple FB login, posting pictures and messages (on your wall).